# Modern pages: page details web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages

The web part called 'Page details' that can display one or more metadata columns on a page, displays terms as text.

Is this the designed use or is there a way to have them hyperlinked?

[image]

Comment: A screen shot would better the understanding of your question.

Comment: Would you be able to specify the link where you want that term to point to?

Comment: In a situation where you apply choice metadata fields about keywords or topic, if those were clickable they should redirect you to the filtered view about that topic of the page list, like the old 'blog' format used to work by clicking on one of the categories